# Flex not working as expected with nested angular material layout

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

Following sample layout:

[image: Flex layout issue]

There is a button with the flex attribute set to 15 (*yellow*) and another set to flex only (*green*). Theoretically, the yellow one hast to be only 15% in height and the remaining available space is used by the green button. As you can see, this is not the case.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Angular Layout Issue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body layout="column" layout-fill>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <div flex="50" layout="row" layout-fill>
        <div flex layout="column" layout-fill>
            <button flex="15">Flex="15"</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
        </div>
        <div flex layout="column" layout-fill>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain me why the flex attribute isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of test I found an answer by myself: The percentage value of the flex="15" isn't evaluated correctly due to the missing height of its parents.

So to solve this problem, you have to apply a height of 100% to the nested flex container and all of its parents, as you can see in the sample below (therefore the layout-fill attribute isn't necessary anymore).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Angular Layout Issue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body layout="column" layout-fill>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <div style="height: 100%;" flex="50" layout="row">
        <div style="height: 100%;" flex layout="column">
            <button flex="15">Flex="15"</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 100%;" flex layout="column">
            <button flex>Flex</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
            <button flex>Flex</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>
    <button flex>Flex</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps anyone.